# JMeter response assertion validation against xml response failed

Tags: perl, jmeter

XML response :

```
<silent><send-sss destination="*1234">TEST mId=dev oId=XXXXXXXXX</send-sms></silent>
```

JMeter response assertion: 
Pattern matching Rule: contains 
Pattern to test: silent

Failed Reason:

```
org.apache.oro.text.MalformedCachePatternException: Invalid expression: *1234
?+* follows nothing in expression
```

Could anyone please let me know what should be there is an assertion that it should fail. I tried using few patterns but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

In [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) to find part of a string you need to choose `Substring` in Pattern Matching rules

> Contains, Matches: Perl5-style regular expressions
>
> Equals, Substring: plain text, case-sensitive

If you choose Contains (meaning regular expression) , you need to escape `*`, then use

```
\*1234
```

Comment: I wish to use Contains because of there few more assertions which require contains.

Comment: @Manoj also choosing `Contains` with only  `silent`  is working

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I omitted out other assertions and run with silent it worked well. In assertion, there is a variable ${code} which is causing this failure. How do we handle this?

Comment: @Manoj if `${code}` is `silent` you can use it in `Patterns To Test` as is: `${code}`

Comment: ${code} which has the same value *1234. and in response assertion, it is reading value *1234 from response XML but somehow validation fails and an error occurs.

Comment: It worked well if I hardcode value \*1234 in assertion but if I do it with variable \*{code} it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

For XML response types it makes more sense to go for [XPath Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Assertion) which allows checking response using arbitrary [XPath queries](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp).

If you want to test presence of `<silent>` tag only the relevant XPath query would be as simple as `//silent`.

With regards to Response Assertion, its **Contains** mode is [PatternMatcher.contains()](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/jakarta/oro/trunk/docs/api/org/apache/oro/text/regex/PatternMatcher.html#contains(java.lang.String,%20org.apache.oro.text.regex.Pattern)) so it requires a **regular expression**, not a simple String so you should be using something like `.*silent.*` as the pattern.

See [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps) article for more information on defining custom pass/fail criteria using JMeter Assertions.